# groovy scripts and classloader - content assist in eclipse - what to do?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Goal: 
I want to define groovy classes in .groovy files as part of a package, but without ever needing to compile them. Then, I want to define groovy scripts in the same package, import the class definitions from the nearby .groovy files, and execute the script... all without compilation.

Problem, 
This appears to be possible using GroovyClassLoader() (and several people have posted how-tos).  However, the problem I have that nobody else seems to reference is that this strategy means that content assist will never be able to identify your classes and methods, and your code will be full of underlines, and receive no error checking.

You might say "Thats just a side effect of using such a dynamic feature, how would eclipse be able to know?", but consider the following:

As I was building my project, I was creating the scripts and the classes in the package just like normal a program. When I add my import statements for my custom classes, Eclipse recognizes everything and content assist is happy.  However, despite content assist being satisfied, it hits a snag when I try to execute a script because eclipse returns: unable to resolve class (presumably because it's still only a groovy file, and not compiled to a class file).

So, I looked around and it looks like I have to comment out the import statement, and then use groovyclassloader to parse the groovy file instead. However, this has the negative side effect of breaking content assist.

Question:  Are my conclusions above all basically correct?

Suggestion: Is there any known way to have content-assist work along-side with GroovyClassLoader? Maybe some way to tell it to ignore failed imports or something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a problem with the way I had configured my classpath. Once I had my folder structure consistent with the package structure, eclipse found my class files and was able to import the classes.